# Add mouse click event to QGraphicsView created with QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Is there a way to create a event to the QGraphicsView created without creating another class and inheriting the QGraphicsView?
I want to know if there's a way to do something like that:

```
ui->gView->AddEvent(click, functionName);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "create an event"? Do you mean a slot?

Comment: What's wrong with subclassing?

Comment: Hi Chris. Nothing, i just wanna know if there's another way to do that.

Comment: Yes Stephen, like that, but i cannot find a slot to do that, i'm a little new on Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle mouse click event for the view, install an [event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) to the view and watch for [`MouseButtonPress`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qevent.html#Type-enum) event.